2FormC relay contact: which is NO/NC
I would like to use this relay:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electric-works/NC2EBD-DC5V/648942
Is pin 7 the common pin between pins 11 & 12?
Is pins 7 & 11 NORMALLY CLOSED? and pins 7 and 12 NORMALLY OPEN?


Yes to all three questions.
7 is common for 11/12, 11 is NC, 12 is NO.
